# Watching write from application at specified memory pointer received from DLL

Tags: c++, memory, dll, watch

I'll try to explain my problem as best I can. So, I have application written in C/C++ (language in client application doesn't matter), which is importing one function from DLL for example uint32_t* GetMemoryPointer(). Then it does write in sequences to this memory pointer like this:

```
uint32_t* ptr = (uint32_t*)GetMemoryPointer();
*ptr = 3;
*ptr = 4;
*ptr = 1050;
```

It does this sequence without any information for DLL that value was changed. Is it possible to watch this value in DLL? I tried to make a thread and in loop seek changes but it's not reliable. Is there a better solution? I'm interested in doing this way: application writes, DLL finds that value was changed, HOLDS application execution then is interpreting this value then ALLOW application to continue execution. Another way without holding application might be pushing on the stack new value but I need to be informed on every change. The platform I'm interested in is Windows. Language doesn't matter may be C or C++. Is it possible to achieve this? It's really important for me and I'm out of ideas. I don't want code but I would like to be informed if it is possible and in which way I need to go. Thanks in advance.

Comment: imho, that's a XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem You should explain what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I explained what I want to achieve, I want to achieve monitoring of small region of memory mapped in DLL (for example 4B variable) and get informed when change from application side occurs. That's all.

Comment: You did not explain why you want to monitor a small region of memory. You have no control on the client application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well on the top of my head, if you could mark the memory as read-only and when ever someone tries to write to it OS will throw an exception/error, you have to catch it. I don't know whether any libraries exists for this, so try googling it.

Answer (score 1):

One options is to implement a `Value` type that holds the actual data to be monitored and use the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to dispatch notifications when the value changes. Start with a simple implementation that holds a value of the desired type (`uint32_t` in this case) along with an assignment operator that invokes callbacks any time the operator changes the value.

The example below does just that and includes a conversion operator to allow a fair amount of operations to be performed with other `uint32_t` values. You can expand on this to meet your requirements including providing a full set of operators (`operator+`, `operator/`, etc.) to make it a bit more robust.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>


class Value
{
    uint32_t    value;
    std::vector<void(*)()> observers;

public:

    Value() : value(0) {}

    //  Allows you to register a observer that gets called when
    //  the value changes
    void RegisterListener(void (*f)())
    {
        observers.push_back(f);
    }

    //  Conversion operator that allows implicit conversions
    //  from Value to uint32_t. 
    operator uint32_t() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    Value& operator=(uint32_t newValue)
    {
        //  Only alert observers if the value is actually changing.
        if (value != newValue)
        {
            value = newValue;
            for (std::vector<void(*)()>::const_iterator it = observers.begin();
                it != observers.end();
                ++it)
            {
                //  Call the observer
                (*it)();
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

void Callback()
{
    std::cout << "value changed\n";
}

int main()
{
    Value value;
    value.RegisterListener(Callback);

    //  Value held in object can be assigned to a uint32_t due to the
    //  conversion operator.
    uint32_t original = value;

    //  Change the value see the callback get invoked
    value = value + 1;

    //  Restore the value to it's original and see the callback get invoked.
    value = original;
}
```

Comment: Sadly this won't work in my situation. When pointer to (uint32_t*) is received from DLL the callbacks and operators from application side are not executed.

Comment: @cafebabe_t Then you're doing it wrong. This solution works just **fine** whether you are doing it from a shared library (DLL), application (EXE) or a combination of both.